# Can I refuse to tell Ontario Trial Judge my employment or daily life?

Tags: ontario

I'm Plaintiff in Small Claims Court case in Ontario Canada. Defendant filed Defence. If we don't settle after Settlement Conference, then we  Trial.  I read [Charter Basics | Your Right to Silence](https://mckayferglaw.com/news/charter-basics-the-right-to-silence/)

> **What is the Right to Silence?**
> In the Canadian legal tradition, the right to silence is a subset of the larger principle against self-incrimination. It is closely related to the rules governing confessions and is also enshrined under section 7 of the *Canadian Charter of Rights and Freedoms*.
>
> At its most basic, the right to silence means that absent any legal obligation to the contrary, no one is obliged to speak to the police or respond to police questioning1. For accused or detained people, this is a Constitutionally protected right. The right to silence means that a detainee has the right to choose whether or not to speak or give a statement to the police2. Regardless of what the police might say, an accused person has *absolutely no obligation* to assist the State with an investigation or prosecution.

In my honest opinion, Defendant's lawyer lied some parts of Defence. I looked up Defendant's lawyer at Law Society of Ontario website, and his record and history are not clean. I don't want him or public know my employment or what I do everyday. I know people have falsely accused at workplace or like debt collectors, harass you at work or employer.

I don't duplicate

- [Can I refuse to tell Settlement Conference Deputy Judge my employment or daily life?](https://law.stackexchange.com/q/56189), because here I ask about Trial, not Settlement Conference.
- [Can non-witnesses legally refuse to answer questions from judge?](https://law.stackexchange.com/q/35920), because that question is New Zealand law. I ask Ontario Canada.

Comment: The judge isn't going to ask you what your job is.  The defence may when cross-examining your own testimony but it'll only be allowed if it's relevant to what you just testified about. If the judge decides that the question is appropriate then you must answer it.

Comment: The question for "what's your occupation" is a standard in German courts, often never referenced again in anything.